# Correlation between noise and error

Tags: matlab, statistics

Consider the following data generated on which filter is added to get suitable deformation:

```
    standarddev=0.1;
    [x,y] = pol2cart(0:0.01:2*pi, 1);
    x1=x-filter(.1*(1-.1), [1 -.1], cumsum(standarddev*randn(size(x))));
    y1=y-filter(.1*(1-.1), [1 -.1], cumsum(standarddev*randn(size(y))));
    plot(x1,y1);
```

I want to study correlation of mean error (between x and x1, and y and y1 independently) and standard deviation.

I am calculating relative mean error by using

```
error_x=mean(abs(x1-x)./x);
```

My variable parameter in the above data will be standard deviation (e.g. 0,0.05,0.1,...,1,...,2). i.e. I want to study how  variation in amount of noise added effects error detected.

I am not getting good correlation between error and standard deviation (as one would expect) because I have added some noise and not just random error whose amount is varying with standard deviation.

How can I take into account the noise added to get good correlation between error and noise.

Comment: This is not at all clear. What do you mean by "I have added some noise and not just random error"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry for lack of clarity. I meant, that rather than merely "x1=x-standarddev*randn(size(x))", I did above one with filter.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, since I added filtered random error, I cannot expect perfect correlation between error and standard deviation. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The way you had attempted to compute `error_x` and `error_y` probably resulted in underestimates due to cancellation of terms, as you were retaining sign information by summing terms `abs(x1-x)./x`.

If you want the mean relative error, then use

```
error_x=mean(abs((x1-x)./x));
error_y=mean(abs((y1-y)./y));
```

The calculation of the relative (population) standard deviation is an alternative:

```
rstddev_x=sqrt(mean(((x1-x)./x).^2));
rstddev_y=sqrt(mean(((y1-y)./y).^2));
```

The population standard deviation is another alternative:

```
stddev_x=sqrt(mean((x1-x).^2));
stddev_y=sqrt(mean((y1-y).^2));
```

Note that division by `x` and `y` may lead to instabilities when these become very small numbers. In that sense it may also be better to compare the deformation parameter to the std dev rather than one of the relative parameters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, I am not calculating standard deviation or population SD. I am calculating [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error) which as you know is not same as SD. Also this statement is a little unclear. Could you elaborate? "You may get better match added noise and that computed from the deviation by using the corrected formulas." Did you mean to try with  your formula? You mean it would give better correlation?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, you really were interested in computing the mean relative error. I amend my answer